# Realm IllegalStateException: Schema validation failed

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-migration

I'm try to use Realm Database in My project
Here are my code snippets

In Application java code

```
public class CoreApplication extends Application {
private static CoreApplication sInstance;
public static final String F_PREFERENCE = "K_PREFERENCES";
public static Realm realm;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    sInstance = this;
    LocaleManager.setLocale(this);

    realm.init(this);
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name("mydb.realm")
            .schemaVersion(2)
            .build();
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);

}

@Override
public void onTerminate() {
    Realm.getDefaultInstance().close();
    super.onTerminate();
}

}
```

RealmObject java class

```
public class CashierTable extends RealmObject implements Serializable {
@Index
@PrimaryKey
private long id;
private String name = "";
private String password = "";
public long getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

 }
```

When I try to call this function when App has started.I have a exception

```
 public static CashierTable getSingleCashierTable() {
    CoreApplication.realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    AtomicReference<CashierTable> cashierTable=new AtomicReference<>();
    CoreApplication.realm .executeTransaction(realm -> {
        cashierTable.set(realm.where(CashierTable.class).findFirst());
    });
    return cashierTable.get();
}
```

Here is a my log result

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.unipay.posApp.CoreApplication: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Schema validation failed due to the following errors:
- Type 'CashierTable' appears more than once in the schema.
```

I cleared cash,but still have same issue.
Can anyone explain me what's wrong in my code?

Comment: In your database schema Cashier Table created more than once. Try the schema of your database. @BekaKK

Comment: alternatively, just for testing and debugging purpose you can set this flag `deleteIfMigrationNeeded()` while creating your configuration at application level and check if the it works, but this will delete your table so use this only for testing and debugging the error.

Comment: look for CashierTable  in different packages of your project, case of duplicate.

Comment: Thanks guys for your attentions. But  my app has started first time and my goal is to check if cashierTable is empty or something else

Comment: yes your are right .It's a different package. is it a necessary to be a same package @Sahil

Comment: you can have only one class of 'CashierTable' extending RealmObject. Both cant exist in schema.

Comment: Do you use Realm 5.0 or nrewer?

Comment: I'm using newer version.I'm created twice .that was a problem.thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have two RealmObject classes with the same class name twice unless you use Realm 5.0+ and use `@RealmClass(name="...` to specify a different table name for at least one of your classes.

```
package io.package.first;

public class Dog extends RealmObject {
}

package io.package.second;

@RealmClass(name="SecondDog")
public class Dog extends RealmObject {
}
```